# Magento horizontal sorting extension

Tags: category-products, extensions

I want to show a horizontal sorting options in magento product category page. I found many extensions in magento extension store. But non of them have horizontal feature. All of them have drop down sorting system.

Here you can see a screenshot of my requirement - http://awesomescreenshot.com/0b357leyed

If anyone know how to do it, or any third party extension, please do let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can copy the file `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml` to your theme and replace this:

```
    <select onchange="setLocation(this.value)">
        <?php foreach($this->getAvailableOrders() as $_key=>$_order): ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $this->getOrderUrl($_key, 'asc') ?>"<?php if($this->isOrderCurrent($_key)): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>>
                <?php echo $this->__($_order) ?>
            </option>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </select>
```

with

```
<div>
<?php foreach($this->getAvailableOrders() as $_key=>$_order): ?>
    <a href="<?php echo $this->getOrderUrl($_key, 'asc') ?>"<?php if($this->isOrderCurrent($_key)): ?> class="active"<?php endif; ?>><?php echo $this->__($_order) ?></a>
<?php endforeach;?>
</div>
```

this will show the dropdown as a set of links.
The current sort order will have the class `active`.
Some styling may be needed (actually you will need to do that for sure), but you can manage it.

Comment: Thanks for your support. I tried this, and did changes as you suggested. Nothing changed from frontend, We are using a third party theme. not the base theme. Here i have attached the file which was located in following directory /app/design/frontend/em0132/default/template/catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml

link - http://www.filedropper.com/toolbar

Can you make the edits and share me the link?

Really appreciate that

Comment: The file is similar to the one from the default theme. Just replace the select that starts with `<select class="sortby" name ="sortby" onchange="setLocation(this.value)">` with the code I provided. And do your styling.

Comment: Nothing changes even after that edit. see - http://prntscr.com/8cjl0j

Comment: This means you are editing the wrong file. or something is cached.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need an extension for this.

Open `app/design/frontend/YOUR_THEME/default/template/catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml`

Then replace the "Sort By" block with the following:

```
    <div class="sort-by">
        <label><?php echo $this->__('Sort By') ?></label>
        <ul>
        <?php foreach($this->getAvailableOrders() as $_key=>$_order): ?>
            <li onclick="setLocation(<?php echo $this->getOrderUrl($_key, 'asc') ?>)"<?php if($this->isOrderCurrent($_key)): ?> class="selected"<?php endif; ?>>
                <?php echo $this->__($_order) ?>
            </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
        <?php if($this->getCurrentDirection() == 'desc'): ?>
            <a href="<?php echo $this->getOrderUrl(null, 'asc') ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Set Ascending Direction') ?>"><img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/i_desc_arrow.gif') ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->__('Set Ascending Direction') ?>" class="v-middle" /></a>
        <?php else: ?>
            <a href="<?php echo $this->getOrderUrl(null, 'desc') ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Set Descending Direction') ?>"><img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/i_asc_arrow.gif') ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->__('Set Descending Direction') ?>" class="v-middle" /></a>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
```

Then you start being creative with some CSS:

```
.sort-by ul li { float:left; border:1px solid black; padding:5px 10px; cursor:pointer; }
.sort-by ul li.selected { border-color:red; }
```

Comment: Thanks for your support. I tried this, and did changes as you suggested. Nothing changed from frontend, . Here i have attached the file which was located in following directory /app/design/frontend/em0132/default/template/catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml

link - http://www.filedropper.com/toolbar

Can you make the edits and share me the link?

Really appreciate that

Comment: The file you attached doesn't contain the changes I have explained? Also make sure your "Block" cache is disabled whilst you're making changes.